# How do you call a method that only exists to make another method name nicer?

Tags: language-agnostic, methods, terminology, facade

I would like to know the proper term for a method whose only reason of existence is to make a method call easier, make a method name sound/read better.

Like that:

```
public function translate($string)
{
    return Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate')->translate($string);
}
```

I could call it an adapter but that's kind of reserved for the Adapter design pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the [Facade](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) design pattern. Usually reserved for interfaces and systems, but there's no reason why it doesn't equally apply to individual functions.

> Adapter and Facade are both wrappers;
>   but they are different kinds of
>   wrappers. The intent of Facade is to
>   produce a simpler interface, and the
>   intent of Adapter is to design to an
>   existing interface

Hmm, so maybe it is an Adapter :)

Personally, I try not to worry too much about what formal definition (if such a thing truly exists for software design) and worry more whether the words I use sufficiently communicate my intent to someone else who's reading. If you say adapter and we understand what's going on, then that's all fine.

Comment: I like Facade, it describes it perfectly in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I'd call that a helper function, a convenience function, or a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

I call them proxy functions, but that's just me.

Comment: If enough people read this answer, though, you might start a trend :-)